# Check for any int type in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, types

I have a function that, among other things, takes in an object and a Type, and converts the object into that Type.  However, the input object is often a double, and the type some variation of int (uint, long, etc.).  I want this to work if a round number is passed in as a double (like 4.0), but to throw an exception if a decimal is passed in (4.3).  Is there any more elegant way to check if the Type is some sort of int?

```
if (inObject is double && (targetType == typeof (int)
                         || targetType == typeof (uint)
                         || targetType == typeof (long)
                         || targetType == typeof (ulong)
                         || targetType == typeof (short)
                         || targetType == typeof (ushort)))
{
    double input = (double) inObject;
    if (Math.Truncate(input) != input)
        throw new ArgumentException("Input was not an integer.");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just a couple of comments - 1) don't forget floats. 2) You might want to use Math.Round(), because sometimes 1.000000001 appears instead of 1.0 due to floating point issues.

Comment: Also sounds like you're duplicating functionality in System.Convert...

Comment: Good points, Jon, I'll make sure to remember floats.  Dave, when you do System.Convert.ChangeType from double to int, it silently does bankers rounding.  This code is to prevent that before the System.Convert call is made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to do what you ask.  I have only tested it for doubles, floats and ints.

```
    public int GetInt(IConvertible x)
    {
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        if (Convert.ToDouble(x) != Convert.ToDouble(y))
            throw new ArgumentException("Input was not an integer");
        return y;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int intvalue;
if(!Int32.TryParse(inObject.ToString(), out intvalue))
   throw InvalidArgumentException("Not rounded number or invalid int...etc");

return intvalue; //this now contains your value as an integer!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a combination of Convert.ToDecimal and x % y, I would have thought, where y = 1 and checking the result ==0;

Comment: I think you'll find that's not true...

?2.4 % 1
0.39999999999999991